# Change Date format for a particular user in Active directory domain through Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

We have many users in different locations in Active directory. For few users the date format is DD/MM/YYYY. So we need to change it to MM/DD/YYYY. Please help with PowerShell command to do that.

Comment: ADDS usually stores timestamps as 64-bit integers without any formatting information, so your question doesn't make much sense. Can you tell us more about the problem you're having and how you've concluded "changing the date format" was the right solution?

Comment: Yes, Changing the date format solves my issue. To elaborate the issue. The users in Newyork need MM/DD/YYYY format but it was DD/MM/YYYY. They are asking us to change it as they require for that particular group of newyork users. 
To do that i need a powershell command

Comment: And how are you currently changing the format (without using powershell)? What tools do you use, which attributes do you target, etc.

Comment: I am logging into the user account manually and changing it from the Control Panel -> Region. 

But i need a much better way to do it without directly logging in into the user account. I want to do it as Domain Administrator through Powershell from Domain controller.

Comment: Gotcha! You might be able to do this with `Invoke-Command remoteComputer01 { Set-WinSystemLocale en-US }` - but a better solution would be to always apply the correct regional settings via [Group Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831791(v=ws.11)) (or an MDM policy)